# PHP while statement only working for one row

Tags: php, css, while-loop

I am trying to have a while statement display all table rows. I have three rows at the moment such as R1 Business R2 Communication and R3 Education. It is display three but all of R1. So instead of listing Business Communication Education it is Business Business Business.

The code I have is:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\includes\format.php');

$con = mysql_connect("server","user","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("foundation", $con);

$result = mysql_query("select * from `database`.`collegemeter");
?>
<?php  

if (!$result || !($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    echo "DB error";
    exit;
}
    $college = $row["college"];
    $date = $row["date"];
    $goal = $row["goal"];
    $url = $row["url"];
    $current = $row["current"];
    $percent = round($current / $goal * 100);
    $totalwidth = 245;
    $ourwidth = $totalwidth * $percent / 100;
    ?>
    <?php 
        $halfofarrowheight = 36;
        $arrowheight = $ourwidth-$halfofarrowheight; 
        if($arrowheight < 0)
            $arrowheight = 0;
    ?>
<?php do { ?>
    <div class="progresswrap">
<p><a href="<?php echo $url;?>"><?php echo $college;?></a></p>
<div class="progresscontainer">
<div class="progress"></div>
</div>
<div class="arrow"> $<?php echo formatmoney($current);?></div>
<h4>$<?php echo formatmoney($goal);?></h4>
</div>
   <?php } while ($row_college = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); ?>
```

So, how do I get it to list ascending down and not repeating the first row?

Answer (score 2):

you should try this one, you were defining your variables only once

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\includes\format.php');

$con = mysql_connect("server","user","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("foundation", $con);

$result = mysql_query("select * from `database`.`collegemeter");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $college = $row["college"];
    $date = $row["date"];
    $goal = $row["goal"];
    $url = $row["url"];
    $current = $row["current"];
    $percent = round($current / $goal * 100);
    $totalwidth = 245;
    $ourwidth = $totalwidth * $percent / 100;

    $halfofarrowheight = 36;
    $arrowheight = $ourwidth-$halfofarrowheight; 
    if($arrowheight < 0)
        $arrowheight = 0;
    ?>
    <div class="progresswrap">
       <p><a href="<?php echo $url;?>"><?php echo $college;?></a></p>
       <div class="progresscontainer">
       <div class="progress"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow"> $<?php echo formatmoney($current);?></div>
    <h4>$<?php echo formatmoney($goal);?></h4>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: That one will list everyone of them excluding the first row it is replaced with >>> and all the numbers are the same, the meter is supposed to adjust based on the numbers in the database so they can see how far along until they hit their goal.

Comment: @EMAWandCougs: I didn't get your comment

Comment: It is show every row in the table except the first one. The numbers in the column rows have a formula which tells where the div is so it is a progress meter and right now they are all the same.

Comment: @EMAWandCougs: so jUst add `LIMIT 1,99999999999` and you're dome

Answer (score 1):

That code is a mess.

a)

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\includes\format.php');
```

Don't use backslashes in paths. Use forward `/` slashes only. PHP will compensate for you if you're on Windows, and auto-transate into backslashes. Backslashes in strings like that open the door to misinterpretation as an escape character, and not a path reference.

b)

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from `database`.`collegemeter");
```

You're missing the closing backtick on collegemeter, and unless your're using a reserved word for your database name, the backticks are totally unnecessary.

c)

```
if (!$result || !($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
```

The proper (+ simplest) method to check for a DB error is:

```
if ($result === false) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Don't check if there's any results by trying to fetch a row. That's what `mysql_num_rows()` is for.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) then
     die("No results!");
}
```

d) Stylistically, do/while loops for database results are a bit ugly. You'd be better off with a more standard:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ... }
```

construct. This would also let you see that you're only defining your `$college` and other vars only ONCE, **OUTSIDE** of your fetch loop. There's no need to fetch the retrieve DB row into individual variables, you can ouput them directly:

```
    while ($row = ...) {
        $money = moneyformat($row['goal']);
        echo <<<EOL
    <div class="progresswrap">
    <p><a href="{$row['url']}">{$row['college']}</a></p>
    <div class="progresscontainer">
    etc...
    EOL;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I made changes. Which it will now pull the college names out the numbers are still not varied. So on the progress bars they all equal the same amount and should be varied based on the percent of what is raised to what the goal is.